# SimpleSchema and AutoForm: Render password field as single input

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I'm working in a project where a "super admin" user can create another users, setting they usernames and passwords. I have an AutoForm `quickForm` rendering a form based upon the `SimpleSchema` attached to the `Meteor.users` collection (using Collection2). 
Following the [Collection2 docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2#attach-a-schema-to-meteorusers) recommendation on attaching a schema to the users collection, my schema looks like this:

```
Usuarios.schema = new SimpleSchema({
    ...
    username: {
        type: String,
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
   "services.password": {
      type: String,
      optional: true,
      autoform: {
         type: 'password'
      }
    },
    ...
});
```

The rendered form looks like this:
[image: Rendered template]

But I would like to have the Password field rendered like the Username one (without the Services panel).
I haven't found a workaround to this. I need to have the Services Object type atribute in the schema or the validation upon user insert fails (with `Accounts.createUser()`), and so, the panel is rendered (because of the Object type of the atribute).

Any ideas on how I could achieve the desired template rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your password is part of the 'service' object, which is why it is automatically rendered inside a afObjectField when using quickForm or quickFields:

> afObjectField
>
> When you use the afQuickField component for a field that is an Object,
>   it is rendered using the afObjectField component unless you override
>   the type or specify options. This happens by default when you use a
>   quickForm for a schema that has a field of type Object.
>
> The afObjectField component renders all of an object field's subfields
>   together as one group. The group is labeled with the name of the
>   object field. The actual visual representation of the group will vary
>   based on which theme template you use. For the "bootstrap3" default
>   template, the group appears in a panel with a heading.

**Solution A: Manual Form Rendering**

To render your password as a single field, you need to set up your autForm manually and reference the fields by using [afFieldInput](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#affieldinput). The form mthen may look like (not tested but code should look like) this:

```js
{{> autoForm id="login" schema=Usuarios.schema}}
    {{> afFieldInput type="text" name="username"}}
    {{> afFieldInput type="password" name="services.password"}}
{{/autoForm}}
```

Which has the advantage that your form looks exactly as you wish but has the disadvantage, that you have to add all extras (validation messages and stuff) manually.

**Solution B: Change your Schema**

When you pull password out of the service group, then you will have the same effect of auto-render as with username: a single input field.

```js
Usuarios.schema = new SimpleSchema({
    ...
    username: {
        type: String,
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    ...
   password: {
      type: String,
      optional: true,
      autoform: {
         type: 'password'
      }
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Solution B worked! Due to my project structure, I couldd't use Solution A. Thanks.